# what happens when a view id is used for setContentView()

Tags: android, android-layout

The Android developer guide seems to suggest that Activity.setContentView() can only be called with a layout ID (R.layout.*). However, I can see view IDs (R.id.*) being used to call the method. For example, in org/xbmc/android/widget/slidingtabs/SlidingTabActivity.java of XBMC, I can see the following code:

```
private void ensureTabHost() {
    if (mTabHost == null) {
        this.setContentView(R.id.slidingtabhost);
    }
}
```

So, what does it mean to call setContentView() with a view ID? Thanks!

**Additional question based on comment** - is "`setContentView(viewId);`" equivalent to "`View v = findViewById(viewId); setContentView(v);`"?

Answer (score 0):

Not

> that Activity.setContentView() can only be called with a layout ID (R.layout.)

Just any view id can be called by the setContentView().

And layout is also a view!

Comment: I can guess what the code might do, but it doesn't seem to be allowed (or at least encouraged) as per the Android developer guide. So, is "setContentView(viewId)" equivalent to "View v = findViewById(viewId); setContentView(v);"? Thanks!

Comment: Yes,you get it. setContentView　method is overloadded ,both setContentView(int) and setContentView(View) are ok.

Comment: So, do you have a source code example of an implementation of setContentView(int)? Alternatively, a documentation of this?

Comment: I think official document is enough. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29

Comment: The official document implies that "setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)" will inflate my_layout.xml. Then, where does it say about what happens with "setContentView(R.id.my_view)"? Which xml file does the id my_view belong to, and which xml file should be inflated?

Comment: I think the document should say:Set the activity content from a view(not only a layout) resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the document should say:Set the activity content from a view(not only a layout) resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.  Actually ,it works like this: If you make a setConentView(R.layout.my_layout); then android os will do the following works:

```
LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null); 
setConentView(layout);
```

if you make a setContentView(R.id.myview);it is also the same way to inflate.

```
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


View myview = inflater.inflate(R.id.myview, null);
setConentView(myview);  `
```

So I say they are the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for digging out the code and show it here. But still, how does Android OS figure out which xml to inflate if only the view id is provided. Document of LayoutInflater.inflate() says "Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource". So, how is the xml resource specified?

Comment: If you look into the source code of LayoutInflater.inflate(int,...), you will see "XmlResourceParser parser = getContext().getResources().getLayout(resource);", and later parser is used to call inflate(XmlResourceParser,...). What getLayout(int) does is "loadXmlResourceParser(id, "layout");". So, the code is assuming a layout id is passed in.

Comment: You have a R.java file that contains all of these information, Android OS can figure out which xml and which view you should inflate from it.

Comment: I agree that it's all there, but problem is - I can't find the code implementing the logic.

Comment: All these logics are deep in the Android Source,it hard to describe in flew words.Just look into the source of ActivityManagerService and PackageManagerService.